# ¿Cambiar Fila Seleccionada de un DataGridView con Codigo en C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Buenas noches a toda la comunidad, mi problema es que tengo un `DataGridView` que contiene nombre de platillos, y dos botones uno que seleccionara la fila de arriba de la fila que se encuentra seleccionada actualmente (si es que hay una mas arriba) y otro que seleccionara la fila de abajo de la fila que se encuentra seleccionada actualmente (si es que hay una mas abajo). Me explico mejor con la imagen: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

actualmente se encuentra seleccionada la segunda fila (carne con zanahoria), quiero que al hacer `click` al primer botón (ignoren los iconos, falta cambiarlos) se seleccione la fila de arriba (burritos de carne) y lo mismo con el botón de abajo, si le picara con la fila que esta seleccionada, bajaría a seleccionar "estofado de carne".

Actualmente este es el código para el primer botón:

```
int cantidadElementos = dgvPlatillosPedidos.Rows.Count;

DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection dgvColec = dgvPlatillosPedidos.SelectedRows;
int posActual = dgvPlatillosPedidos.CurrentRow.Index;

if (posActual < (cantidadElementos - 1))
{
    dgvPlatillosPedidos.Rows[posActual - 1].Selected = true;
}
```

Y este código para el segundo:

```
int cantidadElementos = dgvPlatillosPedidos.Rows.Count;

DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection dgvColec = dgvPlatillosPedidos.SelectedRows;
int posActual = dgvPlatillosPedidos.CurrentRow.Index;
if (posActual < (cantidadElementos - 1))
{
     dgvPlatillosPedidos.Rows[posActual + 1].Selected = true;
}
```

Pero al seleccionar cualquiera de ellos me da el siguiente error: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: si pones un breakpoint en el codigo y ejecutas paso a paso, podrias inspeccionar que valores toman las variables y analizar porque se salen de rando cuando quiere accede a la coleccion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando presionas el boton de subir deberias evalir cuando el index se hace cero, ya que si sigues te irias a un valor negativo, alli no necesitas la cantidad de elementos

```
int posActual = dgvPlatillosPedidos.CurrentRow.Index;

if(posActual == 0)
    return;

dgvPlatillosPedidos.Rows[posActual - 1].Selected = true;
```

Ahora cuando bajas ahi si se evalua sino llegas al final

```
int cantidadElementos = dgvPlatillosPedidos.Rows.Count;
int posActual = dgvPlatillosPedidos.CurrentRow.Index;

if (posActual == cantidadElementos)
    return;

dgvPlatillosPedidos.Rows[posActual + 1].Selected = true;
```

Comment: perfecto me sirvió, era lo justo lo que necesitaba. Gracias